# Multiple uploads red cross problem

Tags: file-upload

When using the multiple uploads function on SharePoint 2010 some of my clients get a red cross over the activeX control and some do not. All clients receive a GPO that adds the URL to trusted sites and all browser versions are IE9 x86. I've even installed the latest version of flash activeX but that made no difference.
One thing I have noticed is that some clients get the red cross and then get a pop-up asking if they want to allow the activex content. When they click allow the control then works. I don't understand why some clients work fine, some get prompted then work and then there are some that just do not work nor do they get prompted!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone reads this...
the fix was simple, the clients it was not working on did not have Office installed locally. The office install includes the office tools that has a DLL that is used during the upload process.